# React Native - Failed to execute aapt

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fcm

I have just configured [React Native FCM](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm), when I try to start the packager:

```
npm install && gradlew clean
```

I get the following error:

```
enter code here
E:\projects\deets-mobile-sp\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-zh-rCN\values-zh-rCN.xml:73: AAPT: warning: string 'instabug_str_empty' marked untranslatable but exists in locale 'zh-CN'

E:\projects\deets-mobile-sp\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-zh-rCN\values-zh-rCN.xml:87: AAPT: warning: string 'instabug_str_plus' marked untranslatable but exists in locale 'zh-CN'

E:\projects\deets-mobile-sp\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-zh-rCN\values-zh-rCN.xml:88: AAPT: warning: string 'instabug_str_powered_by_instabug' marked untranslatable but exists in locale 'zh-CN'

E:\projects\deets-mobile-sp\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:120:31-47: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@mipmap/ic_notif').

E:\projects\deets-mobile-sp\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-zh-rCN\values-zh-rCN.xml:73: warning: string 'instabug_str_empty' marked untranslatable but exists in locale 'zh-CN'

E:\projects\deets-mobile-sp\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-zh-rCN\values-zh-rCN.xml:87: warning: string 'instabug_str_plus' marked untranslatable but exists in locale 'zh-CN'

E:\projects\deets-mobile-sp\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-zh-rCN\values-zh-rCN.xml:88: warning: string 'instabug_str_powered_by_instabug' marked untranslatable but exists in locale 'zh-CN'

warning: string 'instabug_str_record_audio' has no default translation.
E:\projects\deets-mobile-sp\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@mipmap/ic_notif').


:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

 Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4 mins 17.331 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see it is trying to find the resource with name **ic_notif**

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@mipmap/ic_notif').
```

Try the following fix.

1. Go to all of four **android/app/src/main/res/mipmap**-**(hdpi/mdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi)**,
2. Make a copy of **ic_launcher** and rename it to **ic_notif**.

Or you can get these png image files from example [project](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/tree/master/Examples/simple-fcm-client)

Hope this helps you.